# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de todos los botones que he eliminado al enviar un formulario?

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber cómo puedo obtener el valor de todos los botones que he eliminado al enviar un formulario para poder almacenarlos en un solo array. Lo he intentado de muchas formas por lo cual no consigo obtener el resultado que deseo, todos esos datos que se almacenarán en un solo array los deseo utilizar para mandarlos por ajax a un controlador en Codeigniter y posterior utilizarlo en una base de datos para eliminar esos id's.

A continuación subo un video de lo que me sucede cuando cambio de modales.

[Video con el error al guardar y al pasar entre modales](https://vimeo.com/450649688)

**Si elimino todos los valores quisiera que me quede así**

```
idsEliminador = Array[30,31,32]
```

**Si elimino el primero y el tercero que me quede algo así**

```
idsEliminador = Array[30,32]
```

```js
let data = {
    "respuesta": "success",
    "post": [
        {
            "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
            "ID_Cliente": "3",
            "ID_Documento": "2",
            "Subtotal_OTPloteo": "23.75",
            "Impuesto_OTPloteo": "2.85",
            "Total_OTPloteo": "26.60",
            "NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo": "000140",
            "Serie_OTPloteo": "001",
            "Fecha_OTPloteo": "2020-08-19 21:45:12",
            "Nombre_Cliente": "David Alejandro",
            "Apellido_Cliente": "Paucar Briones",
            "Telefono_Cliente": "0992896820",
            "Nombre_Documento": "Factura",
            "Impuesto_Documento": "12",
            "Cantidad_Documento": "141",
            "Serie_Documento": "001",
            "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
            "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
            "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
        },
        [
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "31",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "7.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "8.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "32",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "9.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "11.25"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

// Recorre los datos
data.post[1].forEach(item => {
    // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
    // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
    let html = `<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="idPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo}">
            <input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly></td>
        <td><a href="#" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon eliminarMetros" type="button"><i class="icon-trash">Borrar</i></a></td>
    </tr>`;
    // Agrega fila a la tabla
    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
});


$(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () {
    // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // Eliminar fila y volver a calcular
        $(tr).remove();
        // calculosMetrosPloteo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Metros</th>
                                        <th>Precio Final</th>
                                        <th>Acción</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Es un poco confuso el enunciado, a que te referís con los botones que eliminaste? podes explicar que función cumple el formulario?

Comment: @NicolasCavilla claro, me refiero a que cuando elimino con el boton eliminar quiero capturar el id de la fila que elimina y si elimino 2 filas almacenar esos 2 id's en un solo array

Comment: Simplemente antes del `remove()` puedes guardar el id dentro de un array que tendrás destinado para regsitrar los elementos eliminados.